# Determine if two Java objects are of the same class

Tags: java, class, comparison

I am attempting to do the equivalent of

```
if ( object1.class == object2.class )
{
    //do something
}
```

which of course doesn't work, what method am I overlooking?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If they're from the **exact** same class:

```
boolean result = object1.getClass().equals( object2.getClass());
```

Now if they are compatible classes (if one is of a descendent class to the other):

```
HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
boolean result = hashMap.getClass().isAssignableFrom( linkedHashMap.getClass() );
```

As LinkedHashMap is a subclass of HashMap this **result** variable will be true, so this might probably be better for you as it's going to find exact and subclass matches.

Also, you should avoid using ".class" on variables, as it might not give you the correct result, example:

```
Object someText = "text value";
System.out.println( someText.class.getName() ); //this will print java.lang.Object and not java.lang.String
```

When you're using ".class" you're acessing the variable static property and not the class of the object itself.

Comment: Thanks for including information on comparing hash values. It's more than I wanted to do for this particular issue, but the completeness is appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use object1 instanceof object2?

Comment: **instanceof** takes an object reference to the left and a class name literal to the right, it can't be used the way you're saying.

Comment: I was using Hibernate and comparing objects of an abstract super class, in which case the above answer did not work for me.  Instead I used the following:  obj1.getClass().isInstance(obj2)

Answer (score 16):

You're missing the `getClass()` method,

```
if (object1.getClass().equals(object2.getClass())) 
{ 
    // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
object1.getClass() == object2.getClass()
```

Comment: Use instanceof keyword

Comment: No instanceof requires follows this signature: instance instanceof ClassName, and ClassName must be known at compile time.  Using getClass() allows for waiting till runtime to know the Class.  It's possible the OP could convert to using instanceof, but not from the information provided in the question.  There are other differences wrt to polymorphism as well.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `getClass` method, defined in `java.lang.Class`.

(Source: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)