# How to remove an element from Arraylist by its type

Tags: java, iterator

Say, I have an ArrayList:

```
List<Transaction> txList
```

I also have couple of transactions extending the base class - Transaction:

```
public class ATransaction extends Transaction {...}
public class BTransaction extends Transaction {...}
public class CTransaction extends Transaction {...}
... 10-12 more different kind of Transactions extends Transaction class
```

In some part of the code I am removing these transactions.

```
for (Object tx : transactions) {
    if (tx instanceof ATransaction) {
        CustomerSession.remove((ATransaction) t);
    } else if (tx instanceof BTransaction) {
        CustomerSession.remove((BTransaction) t);
    } else if ...
}

CustomerSession:
    public void remove(Transaction t) {
        Iterator itr = txList.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
           //How to compare the type of iterator with that of the argument "t" passed in the remove method and do an - iterator remove - below when the condition is met
              itr.remove();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `itr.next().getClass().isAssignableTo(t.getClass())`?

Comment: You want to remove all transactions that have the same subtype as Transaction t?

Comment: Yes morbidlycurious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the types, maybe this option with generics would be more suitable. The remove methods will look like this:

```
public void remove(Class<? extends Transaction> cls) {
    Iterator itr = transactions.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (itr.next().getClass().equals(cls)) {
            System.out.println("removing");
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

The signature `Class<? extends Transaction> cls` will ensure that you need to pass a class as parameter that extends Transaction and like `ATransaction`.

Find the code below:

```
public class ListStuff {

List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

public ListStuff() {
    //Add some data
    transactions.add(new ATransaction());
    transactions.add(new DTransaction());
    transactions.add(new ATransaction());
    transactions.add(new ATransaction());
    transactions.add(new CTransaction());
    transactions.add(new ATransaction());
    transactions.add(new BTransaction());
    transactions.add(new CTransaction());
    transactions.add(new BTransaction());
    transactions.add(new BTransaction());
    transactions.add(new CTransaction());
    transactions.add(new CTransaction());
    transactions.add(new DTransaction());

    remove(ATransaction.class); //This will remove all ATrasaction from the list
    remove(BTransaction.class); // This will remove all BTransaction from the list
    transactions.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}


public void remove(Class<? extends Transaction> cls) {
    Iterator itr = transactions.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (itr.next().getClass().equals(cls)) {
            System.out.println("removing");
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}


public abstract class  Transaction {


}


public class ATransaction extends Transaction{

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A";
    }

}

public class BTransaction extends Transaction{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B";
    }
}

public class CTransaction extends Transaction{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "C";
    }
}

public class DTransaction extends Transaction{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "D";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Fixed. The .class was not needed.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use the iterators:

```
    Iterator<Transaction> iterator = transactions.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Transaction tx = iterator.next();
        if (tx instanceof ATransaction) {
            iterator.remove();
        } else if (tx instanceof BTransaction) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to organize the filtering classes, create a map and set true if exists.

first create constants:

```
Constants.ATransaction = "ATransaction ";
Constants.BTransaction = "BTransaction ";
...
```

update your classes, create a middle class:

```
public class MyTransaction extends Transaction {
    public String baseClassName;
    MyTransaction (String baseClassName) {
        super();
        baseClassName = baseClassName;
    }
}

public class ATransaction extends MyTransaction {
    ATransaction() {
        super(Constants.ATransaction);
    }
}
...
```

populate your map with the desired ones at build time:

```
Map<String, Boolean> transactionClasses = new HashMap<>();
transactionClasses.put(Constants.ATransaction, true);
transactionClasses.put(Constants.BTransaction, true);
...
```

then check them while iterating like this:

```
    Iterator<MyTransaction> iterator = transactions.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        MyTransaction tx = iterator.next();
        if (transactionClasses.containsKey(tx.baseClassName)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem with this is the repetition. I have around 15-20 Transaction sub classes for which I will have to do this. Also, it is very old code and large code, I may miss some transactions which I do not have idea about and may cause regressions.

Comment: What type of transactions are you going to eliminate, all? I didn't understand your checking criteria, also I think I get something wrong, are you removing another element from an another list while iterating over transactions? or do you want to remove transactions ?

Comment: If you are going to eliminate just your derived classes, then create another middle class which can be called "MyTransaction" which extends Transaction and then create your A-ZTransaction from MyTransaction, inside list you can choose yours by checking MyTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer in [Determine if two Java objects are of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821810/determine-if-two-java-objects-are-of-the-same-class) the answer depends on whether you seek the exact same class as t, or a derived class thereof.

```
public void remove(Transaction t) {
    Iterator itr = txList.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
          //if(itr.next().getClass().equals( t.getClass())  /*if the current element should be of the exact same type as t */
          if(itr.next().getClass().isAssignableTo(t.getClass()))  /*if the current element is allowed to be a child element of t*/
              itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Please also notice that in the first part of your code, it is better to use the parent `Transaction` class in the enhanced for statement instead of `Object` as it enhances type safety, and that you do not have to down cast to the child type (e.g.,'ATransaction') when removing from the list:

```
for (Transaction tx : transactions) {
  if (tx instanceof ATransaction) {
      CustomerSession.remove(t);
  } else if (tx instanceof BTransaction) {
      CustomerSession.remove(t);
  } else if ...
}
```

or even do everything in a single if with several ||'s instead of the nested if-else