# Changing the fields of an object in an ArrayList then skip that Object next iteration

Tags: java, arraylist

**If you don't want to read every thing, my question is this: How do I change a field of an object in an ArrayList and then skip that object when I loop back through to change an object of the same type?**

Alright, so I have an abstract base class, with 4 derived classes. The base class has a isVacant boolean. I have an arraylist of the type of my base class:

```
    ArrayList<HotelRoom> hotelRooms = new ArrayList<>(20);
```

I obtain user input 1-4 on the type of room they would like to book. After they input 1-4 I determine a function to call on which room to book. 
My problem is that if I try to book multiple rooms of the same type, it just sets one of the rooms of that type to vacant. So if I attempt to book 3 rooms of the same type, it just books one.

```
  while (hotel.getVacantAmount() > 0) {
       int input = getInput();
       bookType(input, hotel);
        System.out.println("Amount of rooms the hotel has that are vacant: " 
       + hotel.getVacantAmount());
  }


 public static void bookType(int input, Hotel h) {
    Hotel hotel = h;
    if (input == 1) {
    hotel.bookDoubleHotelRoom();
    } else if (input == 2) {
    hotel.bookDoubleSuiteHotelRoom();
    } else if (input == 3) {
     hotel.bookKingHotelRoom();
    } else if (input == 4) {
       hotel.bookKingSuiteHotelRoom();
    }
 }
```

This is the function I'm having difficulties with. It finds a room that is of the same type and checks if its vacant, and it sets it to vacant. But after the first one, it just stops. If I remove the break, it sets all the rooms vacancy of that type to false. It's basically one or all.

```
 public double bookDoubleHotelRoom() {
    DoubleHotelRooms doubleRoom = new DoubleHotelRooms();
   for (HotelRoom rooms : hotelRooms) {
       if (rooms.getRoomType() == doubleRoom.getRoomType() && 
                                            doubleRoom.isVacant() == true) {
              rooms.setIsVacant(false);
                break;
           }
   }
    return doubleRoom.getAverageNightlyPrice();
}
```

I tried to make another program that's similar bit dumbed down but had some difficulty. Sorry if I worded it weird, I'm doing my best.

Here's the output for the program:
https://pastebin.com/MktyQ7KY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a doubleroom in the beginning of your bookDoubleHotelRoom function.
Then you check if that room is vacant, I'm guessing you initialize a room as vacant.

You should check rooms.isVacant().

Also there is no need to have a getRoomType field. You can check what kind of class an object is. 
[Determine if two Java objects are of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821810/determine-if-two-java-objects-are-of-the-same-class)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your for loop in the bookDoubleHotelRoom method is going to iterate through all of hotelRooms without consideration to how many rooms are being booked. The if runs, finds a match, does work, then breaks, thus you get one result. I believe your for loop needs a limiting condition, i.e. a number of rooms being booked.

Comment: The person is only supposed to book one room at a time, in its current state. The problem is if they attempt to book another.